# What is the unlock code for Motorola Droid Pro?

Tags: motorola-droid-pro, sim-unlocking

I brought my Motorola Droid Pro back from the USA to Switzerland. It has never been actively on any network, as i bought it through Amazon as a "spare phone" on a Verizon network. I never activated the verizon chip. I am now back in Switzerland and when I try and put in my Swiss SIM card and access the network, it asks me for "SIM network unlock PIN".
Does anyone know how to unlock it?
thanks.

Comment: I have also got a new Verizon Motorola Droid Pro from Amazon Wireless as a replacement phone. It was never activated in the USA. I am trying to get it unlocked remotely (using IMEI) from India. Unfortunately Verizon is not giving the code as I am not a Verizon Customer ( They need you to be a customer atleast for 90 days). I tried couple of Unlocking Services and both of them gave the same unlock code. It didn't work. They are saying that Verizon might have changed the Unlock Code and only Verizon can unlock it. I am stranded. Any solutions please?

Answer (score 3):

See this thread on XDA-Developers [Unlock Motorola Droid Pro](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=866922):

> You simply call Verizon and tell them
>   you're going to spend some extended
>   time in Europe and you want the
>   ability to unlock the phone and change
>   out the SIM card so you can use the
>   phone as a local phone without all the
>   charges, etc. They'll then tell you
>   that you won't have the Verizon
>   guarantee of service, etc., if you
>   remove the SIM card while overseas.
>
> ... They gave me
>   a code to use when and if I ever
>   insert a foreign SIM card in the
>   phone. At that time, it will prompt me
>   for the unlock code.

Comment: i tried that, but they said seing as it had never been activated on the verizon network they don't bave the code - but surely the code is tied into the IMEI and not the service contract?

Comment: Probably they just don't want to give it to you because they never got to make money off you having a plan for that phone.

Comment: If they're going to be difficult like that, then probably your only option is to pay one of the phone unlocking services on the net, who should be able to give you an unlock code for a small fee (and if they try to charge you a lot, shop around for someone else).