# How to unlock a "network sim" in order to use a Android phone?

Tags: sim-unlocking, htc-mytouch

I got an old Android phone (HTC MyTouch) from someone in the States. The phone says "T-Mobile" on the top.

I put in my O2 SIM chip (Germany), turned it on, typed in the SIM, but then it asks me to type in a "**SIM network unlock pin**".

I went to T-Mobile here in Germany and they said to "contact T-Mobile in America" who may be able to unlock it for me.

I went to the O2 shop in Germany and they said it would definitely not be possible to use this Android phone with my O2 SIM chip.

**Before I sink hours into contacting T-Mobile in the States, can someone tell me from experience if it is (technically and legally) possible to use this Android phone in Germany?**

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7027/i-just-bought-an-lg-optimus-t-in-the-us-how-do-i-unlock-it-for-my-country http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4558/unlock-code-for-motorola-droid-pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to purchase an unlock code.

You will probably find a number of companies via google a I have used a couple, which I'm not sure I'm allowed to post here so I recommend you visit Modaco, the site run by Paul O'Brien of custom rom and rooting fame.

Click the Android part of the site and at the bottom of the site or via a web banner to the right, you'll see one of their official sponsors that does HTC codes for $20.

Comment: the ad seems to be gone / personalized. is there an updated way to find a trusted (?) unlocker?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you have been on T-Mobile for some time, you could just contact them (online chat works too) and they will give the unlock code to you. Their online chat system works pretty well.

And it is definitely legal to use the phone in another country. It's *yours*.

As for technical issues, I have not heard of SIM card compatibility issues before (except for size issues between micro SIM and normal SIM). My hunch is that the O2 guy meant something concerning differences between GSM and CDMA. I know that T-Mobile uses a GSM network, but I am not too sure about Vodafone.

Answer (score 0):

Is your phone CDMA or GSM. If its CDMA no one can help you. You need to continuce with T-Mobile. If it's GSM read on.

As your phone is under contract you need to use T-Mobile with your phone. Once the contract terms is over you can get it unlocked by contacting T-Mobile support.

If you want to get it unlocked before the contract ends you can do it by purchasing SIM unlock codes. I found these people on facebook https://www.facebook.com/SamsungSimUnlock and got my wife's HTC phone unlocked.

PS: In some countries it is illegal to unlock phone before the contract terms ends. Please check you local laws before doing so.

Comment: T-Mobile will always be GSM.

Comment: Sorry. I am not from US so I dont know about the packages and the carriers there. Anyhow thank you for the reply.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure it's law now that if you want an unlock code from a mobile network carrier they are required to give it to you. But it definitely is not illegal. However, it may be even easier to just root the phone instead. This should (depending on how you root it) unlock your phone in the process.

As for your O2 SIM chip, I'm not sure how foreign SIM cards work in American phones, but it's definitely worth a shot.